# Why am I getting an output of "u" when trying to map a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make corn also have "juice" at the end of it, and I was experimenting with a 2d array. If I take out the array and make it 1d, then I am able to get "juice" at the end of every fruit. The anomaly is the corn, which I cannot get to display "corn juice." In fact, the following output gives me "u."

Why am I getting an output of "u" with the following code, and how do I use the mapping method to return "corn juice" within the 2d array?

```
fruits = ["corn"["apple","orange","grape"]];

var fruitJuice = fruits.map(function (fruit){
return fruit + " juice";
});

fruitJuice[0][0];
```

Comment: `["corn"["apple","orange","grape"]];` is not a 2d array, it is not a valid JS array

Comment: @mplungjan any idea why I am getting an output of "u" with this code?

Comment: `fruit` within `map()` is `"undefined"` hence the `u` (first char at index [0] (twice))

Comment: Try a few console.log and hit f12 to see why

Comment: Add a comma after `corn` and you will get the juice :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fruits = ["corn"["apple","orange","grape"]];
```

does not quite make sense. **Do this**

```
fruits = ["corn","apple","orange","grape"]; // a normal linear array
```

Unless you meant this?

```
fruits = ["corn",["apple","orange","grape"]]; //an array  with  a string and array (2d)
```

OR this?

```
fruits = {"corn":["apple","orange","grape"]}; //an object where corn represents the array
```

**UPDATE: to access all levels and add 'juice', although a bit of an odd thing to do in this case,  i would just do - using map for this would be unhelpful**

```
fruits = ["corn",["apple","orange","grape"]];

juices = [];
for (var i in fruits){
     if(fruits[i].constructor === Array){
        for (var x in fruits[i]){
              juices.push(fruits[i][x] + " juice");
        }
     }else{
        juices.push(fruits[i] + " juice");
     }
}

alert(juices);

//juices
```

this assumes the element could be either an array or string....

Comment: fruits = ["corn",["apple","orange","grape"]];

Is what I am after, now I can display "corn juice." using: fruitJuice[0];

But now instead of getting apple juice, orange juice and grape juice, I get "apple,orange,grape juice." Any idea how to make each fruit have "juice" at the end of it within the 2d array?

Comment: Thanks man. That code actually got pretty deep but I understand what you did and I am able to get "juice" at the end of everything in the arrays. Just to be sure, it is not possible to do that solely with the mapping method, right?

Comment: Yea, so this is a solution based on the problem you've described - ideally what you have described would not be quite how it is... so that it doesnt have to come checking data types like this, etc. You could map but it would not make things more simple :)